# Can a synchronous input be done in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in the possibility of using JavaScript for an introductory language for students. The missing piece for me is the ability to provide a blocking equivalent to the input() command that is available in other languages.

Using console-only versions of JavaScript, like [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey), would be a solution. SpiderMonkey has a readline() command. But I think the students would be more interested in code that ran inside a web browser. It would be nice if students could share with their friends their version of the classic "guess a number between 1 and 10" game.

The JavaScript window.prompt() command would also work, but the fact that it pops up a completely separate window isn't ideal. I'd like an in-document input field that works the same way. Is there such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prompt()` is the only thing that comes to mind as a blocking input method. I don't exactly know why you need to make it blocking, but perhaps you can use the [jQuery blocking plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) 
to achieve the blocking (at least the UI)?

Comment: The jQuery blocking plug-in blocks the web page, but doesn't block the running code. I'm hoping for the blocking the code and letting the browser keep running.

Answer (score 0):

You con use an input text and a button. when button is pressed get and process the text and clean the input text for a new usage.

In addition you can consider use http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

In a web browser, you can use [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt). It's very old-fashioned (like `alert`) and behaves *(almost entirely)* synchronously. So:

```
var str;
str = prompt("Enter some text: ", "");
console.log("You entered '" + str + "'");
str = prompt("Enter some more text: ", "");
console.log("You entered '" + str + "'");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ixerof) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ixerof/edit)

Instead, though, I think I'd probably recommend getting the students used to using callbacks, and providing some utility code (or just using some pre-built thing). The sooner they get used to it, the better, and it's not that complicated. For instance, the asynchronous version of the above could readily be:

```
asynchronousPrompt("Enter some text: ", "", function(text) {
    console.log("You entered '" + text + "'");
    asynchronousPrompt("Enter some more text: ", "", function(text) {
        console.log("You entered '" + text + "'");
    });
});
```

Comment: These students haven't even been introduced to writing their own functions yet. Writing their own callbacks would be premature. 

I'd like them to be able to write code that can allow them to learn about creating expressions, if statements, and loops without the complexities of functions, callbacks, and even HTML. Some kind of console-type setup, but in the browser instead.

Comment: @PaulVincentCraven: LOL! Fair enough. So `prompt` would be the way to go initially, then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Synchronous Execution in JavaScript](http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2009/05/27/synchronous-execution-in-javascript/) provides a nice write up and example code for performing synchronous operations using JavaScript.

Comment: This article talks about putting code in a list and then sequentially running eval()'s on it. That works great, except when you need branching or looping.

Comment: @PaulVincentCraven - branching or looping would probably have to be controlled by your "main" process which would invoke the necessary functions based on condition criteria

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find a great way to do that and I'm not sure you should try. I assume this is a very basic course in programming and you want the students to get the feeling they can accomplish something. In that case I would provide them with html code that contains the input field, button and an onclick handler hooked to a function already.

Students will quickly learn to add input fields and buttons. Just because you and I learned to program in text only environments doesn't mean that todays students should.

Answer (score -1):

Would NodeJs be a solution for you? It supports a REPL afaik. And it also has a STDIO implementation